# C# - Cannot use Replace method

Tags: c#

so for some reason, I try to use Replace and it doesn't work good :

```
if (counter >= Type.Count)
{
    counter = 0;
}

NewTxT.Add(Type[counter].Replace("KW", Keyword[rnd.Next(0, Keyword.Count)])
    .Replace("PT", PageType[rnd.Next(0, PageType.Count)])
    .Replace("NW", Keyword2[rnd.Next(0, Keyword2.Count)]
        .Replace("PF", PageFormat[rnd.Next(0, PageFormat.Count)])
        .Replace("DE", Domains[rnd.Next(0, Domains.Count)])
        .Replace("SF", SearchFunction[rnd.Next(0, SearchFunction.Count)])));

counter++;
```

this is what I need to replace:

```
SFKW.PT?PF= + SFKW
```

for some reason, it replace the

```
KW, PT
```

but it doesn't replace SF and PF...

I have been trying to fix it for hours but I cant find the reason this is happening

Comment: I would refactor this code to be more readable. it will be much easier to find the issue.

Comment: What are you trying to replace them with? what are those array you are referencing? what is your expected output?

Comment: Could you please add the declarations of your string arrays(Type,Keyword,PageType)?

Comment: You're missing a closing `)` just before `.Replace("PF"...`, so you're replacing "PF" in the Keyword, not the original text.

Comment: Gosh that's a long line of code. It would immensely improve readability if you broke this down.

Comment: And it'll be easy to answer if you told us what `Type`, `Keyword`, `PageType`, `PageFormat` etc are. Please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as instructed in the link.

Comment: If you are doing multiple replace calls, put your strings in a Dictionary that you loop through to do the replacement.  This is very unreadable and ugly

Comment: @Alex you're missing a `)`.

Answer (score 3):

Reformatting this code will make it both much clearer, and reasonably obvious what the issue is - you've put a closing `)` in the wrong place:

```
if (counter >= Type.Count) counter = 0;
NewTxT.Add(Type[counter]
    .Replace("KW", Keyword[rnd.Next(0, Keyword.Count)])
    .Replace("PT", PageType[rnd.Next(0, PageType.Count)])
    .Replace("NW", Keyword2[rnd.Next(0, Keyword2.Count)] // <-- There's a missing ")" here...
    .Replace("PF", PageFormat[rnd.Next(0, PageFormat.Count)])
    .Replace("DE", Domains[rnd.Next(0, Domains.Count)])
    .Replace("SF", SearchFunction[rnd.Next(0, SearchFunction.Count)]))); // <-- ...and one too many here
counter++;
```

The following should therefore do what you want it to:

```
if (counter >= Type.Count) counter = 0;
NewTxT.Add(Type[counter]
    .Replace("KW", Keyword[rnd.Next(0, Keyword.Count)])
    .Replace("PT", PageType[rnd.Next(0, PageType.Count)])
    .Replace("NW", Keyword2[rnd.Next(0, Keyword2.Count)])
    .Replace("PF", PageFormat[rnd.Next(0, PageFormat.Count)])
    .Replace("DE", Domains[rnd.Next(0, Domains.Count)])
    .Replace("SF", SearchFunction[rnd.Next(0, SearchFunction.Count)]));
counter++;
```